# Installing wireless adapter drivers from CD (no ethernet connection...)

Tags: wireless, drivers

I recently built my first computer and installed the newest version of Ubuntu on it (note: I'm new to Linux). However, I didn't have a wireless card (and no ethernet either), so I got a wireless USB (netis ac1200 wireless dual band usb adapter). It came with a CD with drivers for Linux but I have no idea how to install them! Yes, it has a readme and a PDF for install instructions. I read through them and tried to follow the directions but I keep getting errors when I try to install with the terminal.

The install.sh file on the CD is supposed to be what I can use to easily install the drivers. However when I right-click the file on the CD and try to set the permissions to run it as a file it doesn't allow me to do that.

Meanwhile, if I move the install.sh file to the Desktop and allow it to run as a program and then try sudo ./install.sh I get a bunch of errors when trying to run it (it can't find the Makefile, etc.).

Any suggestions before I go any further?

I really don't want to have to go back to Windows but this is getting very frustrating! Two weeks I've been struggling with this install of drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can't. As you've already seen, the install.sh can't be made executable on the CD as it is a read-only medium. You need read-write-execute.

Next, the install.sh needs other files that are in the folder with the install.sh, so you'd need to drag and drop the entire folder to any convenient place, your desktop, for example.

Even when you do this, the install.sh actually compiles source code. Compiling requires *linux-headers* which are included in recent Ubuntu versions but not some older versions. You also need a package called *build-essential* which is a meta package of other packages.

Finally, many of the driver discs are too old to be useful; that is, they were built for kernel version 2.8 or some such, and will not compile on kernel versions 3.xx and 4.xx.

I suggest you identify the device from the command:

```
lsusb
```

Post the result and let's see if we can help you.

Comment: thanks for your help. So I did as you instructed. I got 9 listings. Most are Intel and Linux foundation root hubs. I think the USB device in question is this: Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:8812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.

Comment: Before I propose an off-line solution, please confirm your kernel version: `uname -r` and your architecture: `arch`. Thanks. It will be a difficult process unless you can beg or borrow a temporary internet connection by tethering, ethernet or any means possible.

Comment: ok, so I did that. My uname -r gave this: 3.16.0-30-generic and my arch gave this: x86_64

Comment: ok so I tried just moving all the files from the CD to the desktop and installing from there. It 'worked' except it also corrupted my system so I had to re-install it. Maybe I just need to find the correct driver I need online or call tech support for Netis. I'll try both..

Comment: thanks for all your help. I finally got it working. I downloaded the newest drivers from the Netis website and put them on my USB stick and then installed them with the same directions. Once I restarted my machine and configured the direction of the antennae on the USB WLAN I got blazing fast speeds. Finally. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to just leave the script in the folder on the CD, as it most likely references other files relative to its location, then navigate to it using `cd` and run it from the terminal. (Keep in mind that external drives in Linux aren't mounted as D: and E: like Windows, but rather a folder, such as /media//. You'll probably want to figure out its mount point from the GUI and then navigate to it in the terminal.) I've always had trouble running .sh scripts from the GUI, so I'd stick with the terminal. If there's a .deb, you can probably run that from the GUI, but since it includes a .sh file, you'll probably want to try that first.

Comment: Sorry, it won't execute on the CD.

Comment: @Stephen Kendall thanks for your answer. As chili said, I tried that, def. seemed like the way to go for me, but couldn't do it. Got command not found and permission denied errors.

Comment: Permission denied errors makes me think you forgot to use `sudo`, but as your initial question included it, I doubt that would be the problem... I think @chili555 will have to take it from here. Best of luck!