# Grub - what now

Tags: system-installation

This OS is so difficult. So frustrated. I tried installing drivers and it was impossible. When I finally got it to install it messed up the OS. So I tried re-installing the OS with a USB stick. It seemed to reinstall ok, but now when I login I just get grub> (instead of the login screen)...I have no idea what to do now.

I tried ls and see (hd0), and a bunch more
they are all either FAT or unknown or ext2 and when I try ls (hd0,1)/ I just see efi/

No idea where to go from here. Ideas? Thoughts? Suggestions?

Comment: Are you planning to dual-boot with windows? What was your setup (different partitions or all in one)? Why did you use ext2 over ext4? Which version did you install (15.04, 14.10 ...)? Did you receive any errors? Does the live version ("try ubuntu" when starting with the installation USB) run nicely? What did you do to mess up the OS?

Comment: @Fiximan no. i wanted just one linux OS. I didn't pick anything. I installed 14.04.3-64bit. No errors. I put it on USB originally and installed it that way and it worked fine. I tried to install a driver from the CD so I could get my wireless USB working otherwise i have no internet on the machine. It sort of installed - terminal said it went fine but I got about 1,000 errors in an error report. Tried restarting and whole system wouldn't function although it would boot...windows wouldn't close, etc. So I tried re-install with usb again...booted it from that, went fine..now i have 'grub>'.

Comment: @Fiximan yes it works ok when I 'try it' without installing it. Sorry it takes me so long I have to plug the keyboard back and forth between machines so i can use the internet and type.

Comment: No worries. Are you sure the CD for the driver and the USB are matching versions? How did you do the installation? Which driver are we talking and where did you get it from? Best and thorough solution now would be to reinstall (again - sorry) the OS (and better do yourself a favour: separate /home, and use ext4 for all partitions if you have no important data there yet) - then get a wired LAN connection for installing drivers (if possible). For a quick repair, use the "try ubuntu" option and start the "boot repair" program.

Comment: @Fiximan ok, I got the OS working again. Before getting your message I just used the USB again and selected the option to delete all partitions on my SATA and re-install Linux, before I had it just delete one partition and re-install and I guess that caused the problem...I thought I only had one on there originally but maybe not. Anyway, it's good now. As for your suggestion about Ethernet...I don't have an Ethernet card in my machine, that's why I bought the USB...you think I should return it and get Ethernet instead?

Comment: Note: I need wireless eventually because the router is way too far from where I need my computer..

Comment: I understand, also a laptop without WLAN in unbearable, but usually a wired LAN connection for installing your WLAN driver is simpler than doing the installation from a CD - but an ethernet is not a must have once that WLAN is set (I never even used mine). I am just a bit astonished, that the driver is not part of the standard Ubuntu setup.

Comment: @Fiximan Hi again, yes, well, actually I have another thread started on that particular issue. In short: it's a driver that came on a CD with the USB WLAN I purchased. It's a Netis USB...has Linux drivers but always messes up my OS when I try to install it. See this thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/660681/installing-wireless-adapter-drivers-from-cd-no-ethernet-connection/660752?noredirect=1#comment952157_660752. Also if you want to put your answer into an 'answer' here I can give you credit and close this issue. Thanks again!

Comment: It's fine, problem solved. However: next time get the latest driver from the manufacturer's homepage instead of using the one from the CD again - The dependencies might have changed as the kernel gets updated.

Comment: Did you get your problem fixed then? If so it might helpful to post an answer below outlining what you did to achieve that. Or, if you prefer, we can just close this question and move on :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what I ended up doing to fix my problem. It involved me re-installing Ubuntu multiple times (not a very difficult thing to do it turns out). Since I had Ubuntu on a USB stick (that's how I installed it originally also), you just boot the computer from it and choose 'install'.

It then asks you if you want to reinstall it. I selected this option and it did things I can't recall, but they weren't good. Later, I booted again to the USB and on the USB options menu I found another option called something like 'wipe entire drive clean and reinstall'...so I selected that one and it did a great job. The new installation worked perfectly...just as it had before.